# Callback function with aerospike_query_foreach giving build error

Tags: c++, aerospike

i am trying to create a c++ client for aerospike server. I am able to insert the data using lists. Later i want to retrieve data using aerospike_query_foreach call. In this call we need to send one callback function. I tried to send a callback function called processresult defined in same class with bool return type. But, it give error like type mismatch with library function. Code i wrote is

```
as_query query;
as_error error;
as_query_init(&query, pConfigInfo->inputNsName.c_str(), (*itr).c_str());
as_query_where_inita(&query, 1);
as_query_where(&query, "rawData", as_integer_range(startinterval,stopinterval));
//Execute the query for database specified.
if (aerospike_query_foreach(&m_asConnection, &error, NULL, &query, CDataBaseManager::ProcessResults, NULL) != AEROSPIKE_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "aerospike_query_foreach() returned %d - %s", err.code, err.message);
    as_query_destroy(&query);
}
```

My call back function is

```
bool CDataBaseManager::ProcessResults(const as_val* p_val, void* udata)
{
   if (! p_val)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "query callback returned null - query is complete.");
      return true;
   }
}
```

Compile Error is

```
database_manager.cpp:126:112: error: cannot convert âCDataBaseManager::ProcessResultsâ from type âbool (CDataBaseManager::)(const as_val*, void*) {aka bool (CDataBaseManager::)(const as_val_s*, void*)}â to type âaerospike_query_foreach_callback {aka bool (*)(const as_val_s*, void*)}â
   if (aerospike_query_foreach(&m_asConnection, &error, NULL, &query, CDataBaseManager::ProcessResults, NULL) != AEROSPIKE_OK)
                                                                                                                ^
make: *** [database_manager.o] Error 1
```

Please guide me, if i am doing anything wrong in this call?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a method as 'aerospike_query_foreach_callback'.
**Use a function which doesn't belong to any namespace.**
For example, change your function to :

```
bool ProcessResults(const as_val* p_val, void* udata)
{
   if (! p_val)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "query callback returned null - query is complete.");
      return true;
   }
}
```

Call it as:

```
aerospike_query_foreach(&m_asConnection, &error, NULL, &query, ProcessResults, NULL)
```

Comment: yes, i made it as static function to call in the foreach loop. Thanks for response.